# Spring boot app to accept user input and saving without any database

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

I do have a requirement to create a spring boot and angular application without the use of any database, not even in memory db.The application should accept user input and be displayed in Angular.

```
// The controller class looks like bellow

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping({ "/api" })
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    userService userService;

    @PostMapping
    public Computer create(@RequestBody Computer computer) {
        return computerService.save(computer);
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<Computer> findAll() {
        return computerService.findAll();
    }
}

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

private static List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

private static int Count = 3;

static {

    user.add(new User(34, 2000.22,new Date()));
    user.add(new User(60, 3000.44,new Date()));
    user.add(new User(45, 2000.22,new Date())); 
}
```

And of course there is a userService class with the methods in the implementation class.Is it possible to use hashMap to accept data and then display in Angular without first storing the data in a file or database?. Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

}

Comment: You can store it in the `application.properties` file.

Comment: of course it is possible. save the data got in the hashmap and return when asked